# How to timeout page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, playwright

Here is a code snippet. It gets stuck after a while. I need to add timeout to this:

```js
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
console.log("now here");
await page.waitForSelector('.classifiedDetailTitle');
console.log("wating");
await page.waitForSelector('.classifiedInfo ');
console.log("now waiting");
await page.waitForSelector('.classifiedInfoList');
console.log("waitign again");
await page.waitForSelector('.selected');
console.log("yahoo");
title = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.classifiedDetailTitle>h1'), element => element.textContent));
console.log("page eval");
//price = await page.evaluate(() => (document.querySelectorAll('.classifiedInfo >h3'), element => element.textContent));
price = await  page.$$eval(".classifiedInfo >h3", paragraphs => paragraphs.map(p => p.innerText.trim()));
console.log("this page eval");
key = await  page.$$eval(".classifiedInfoList>li>strong", paragraphs => paragraphs.map(p => p.innerText.trim()));
console.log("key");
value = await  page.$$eval(".classifiedInfoList>li>span", paragraphs => paragraphs.map(p => p.innerText.trim()));
console.log("value");
//info = info.split("")

var dict = {}
features = await  page.$$eval(".selected", paragraphs => paragraphs.map(p => p.innerText.trim()));
console.log("with features");
dict["features"] = features;
key.push("url");
key.push("title");
key.push("price");

value.push(url);
value.push(title);
value.push(price);

console.log(price);

for(let keys = 0; keys < key.length; keys++){
  dict[key[keys]] = value[keys];
}

writer.write(dict);
```

How do I make it timeout after n seconds? It makes the webpage get stuck after a while and I have to manually close it in order for it to keep running.

Comment: Where does it get stuck? Setting `timeout: 0` in the first line disables timeout on page.goto. If the web page does not send the `load` event the page.goto promise will never resolve.

Comment: @arjun27 it specifically gets stuck at page.evaluate

Comment: Can you file an issue on the Playwright GitHub repo? Please attach logs by setting the `DEBUG=pw:api` environment variable.